# Having some trouble with neighbors(int parameter) in Adjacency Matrix (java)

Tags: java, matrix

I need a step in the right direction. I have been trying to figure this one out for the past few hours.

I've setup my adjacency matrix but can't figure out how the neighbors(int i) method can figure how many adjacent vertices are incident to vertice i, and then get neighbors to return a collection of those incident vertices in integer form.

Code is like

```
 public class Graph {

// Setup privately modified variables which will define the graph

// These two parameters are storage variables for edges and vertices
private int vertex;
private int edge;

// This will be the adjacency matrix to represent out graph, this will represent edges.
private static boolean[][] adj_Matrix_Edges;
// This will be an array to store the vertices.
private int[] adj_Matrix_Vertices;

// first step will be to setup the graph, using this constructor
public Graph() {

    // Initialize the scanner for user's input on vertices.
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // define local variable for user input.
    int num_vertices;
    num_vertices = vertex;

    // ask for user input
    System.out
            .println("Please enter how many nodes will be on the graph: ");
    num_vertices = scan.nextInt();

    // make a runtime exception for nonnegative values.
    if (num_vertices < 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Number of vertices cannot be a nonnegative value");}

    System.out.println("There are now " + num_vertices + " vertices  in the graph.");

    // Vertices are stored in a one dimensional array.
    adj_Matrix_Vertices = new int[num_vertices];


    // A graph is created based on the user's specifications, N X N or (n^2) graph.
    adj_Matrix_Edges = new boolean[num_vertices][num_vertices];
}

//This method validates whether or not two vertices are adjacent, returns true if adjacent false otherwise.
public boolean adjacent(int i, int j) {

    if (adj_Matrix_Edges[i][j] == true) {
        System.out.println("The vertex " + i + " and vertex " + j + " are adjacent.");
        return true;}
    else{
        System.out.println("The vertex " + i + " and vertex " + j + " are not adjacent");
        return false;}
}

public void neighbors(int i){

    int j = i;

}


// This method adds an edge if the two int values in the 2-d boolean array are false, converts to true otherwise stays true if already an edge present
public void addEdge(int vertex_add_1, int vertex_add_2) {

    if (adj_Matrix_Edges[vertex_add_1][vertex_add_2] == false) {
        adj_Matrix_Edges[vertex_add_1][vertex_add_2] = true;
        adj_Matrix_Edges[vertex_add_2][vertex_add_1] = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("There is already an edge between vertex " + vertex_add_1 + " and vertex " + vertex_add_2 + ".");
    }
}

// This method removes an edge if the two int values in the 2-d boolean array are true, converts to false, otherwise it stays false if no edge present
public void removeEdge(int vertex_remove_1, int vertex_remove_2) {

    if (adj_Matrix_Edges[vertex_remove_1][vertex_remove_2] == true) {
        adj_Matrix_Edges[vertex_remove_1][vertex_remove_2] = false;
        adj_Matrix_Edges[vertex_remove_1][vertex_remove_2] = false;
    } else {
        System.out.println("There is no edge between vertex "
                + vertex_remove_1 + " and vertex " + vertex_remove_2);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Graph graph = new Graph();

    graph.addEdge(1, 2);
    graph.removeEdge(0, 1);
    graph.adjacent(1, 2);
    graph.adjacent(2, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < adj_Matrix_Edges.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < adj_Matrix_Edges[i].length; j++){
            System.out.println(adj_Matrix_Edges[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("-----");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What does each non-zero element of an adjacency matrix represent?

Comment: it would represent true since it is a 2-d boolean array

Comment: But what does `true` represent in the context of an adjacency matrix?

Comment: it would represent an edge for the respective vertices in the adjacency matrix

Comment: Ok, so in column `i`, all the `true` elements represent what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over the column in the adjacency matrix that represents edges of the vertex. If you want to get the number of adjacent vertices, just sum the true values in that column. If you want to get a collection of neighbours, return indices in the column for which there is a true value

```
public List<Integer> getNeighbors(int vertex) {
    List<Integer> neighbors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < adj_Matrix_Edges.length; i++){
        if(adj_Matrix_Edges[vertex][i]) {
            neighbors.add(i);
        }
    }
    return neighbors;
}
```

EDIT:

```
 public int[] getNeighborCount(int vertex) {
    int neighborCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < adj_Matrix_Edges.length; i++){
        if(adj_Matrix_Edges[vertex][i]) {
            neighborCount++;
        }
    }
    return neighborCount;
 }

public int[] getNeighbors(int vertex) {
    int[] neighbors = new int[getNeighborCount()];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < adj_Matrix_Edges.length; i++){
        if(adj_Matrix_Edges[vertex][i]) {
            neighbors[j++] = i;
        }
    }
    return neighbors;
}
```

Comment: Anyway to iterate without invoking the ArrayList class? I was specifically trying to avoid using that method, hence why I am stumped.

Comment: well, you could count the adjacent vertices first, and then instantiate an array of that size

Comment: Marcin, what is the if statement checking for exactly in that iteration? I understand that the for loop is scanning the column from the parameter value but confused about the second part. The ArrayList class is new to me. Thank you for providing a quick response, I really want to understand it all rather than just code.

Comment: `if(adj_Matrix_Edges[vertex][i])` is the equivalent of `if(adj_Matrix_Edges[vertex][i] == true)` but you can omit the equality sign since `adj_Matrix_Edges` contains boolean values. The statements checks if there is an edge between your vertex and vertex `i`